# Ruby on Rails Why do I get the error: Array can't be coerced into Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, decimal, bigdecimal

I am making a cinema system in Ruby on Rails, I am currently trying to get it to display the total price of each booking.

I am trying to do this through this method in booking.rb:

```
def total_price
    adult_price = Price.where("name = ?", "Adult").pluck(:price)
    child_price = Price.where("name = ?", "Child").pluck(:price)
    senior_price = Price.where("name = ?", "Senior").pluck(:price)
    student_price = Price.where("name = ?", "Student").pluck(:price)
    user = user_id
    showing = showing_id
    price = 0
    seats = Booking.where("user_id = ? and showing_id = ?", user,showing)
    seats.each do |seat|
        if not seat.adult_seats.blank?
            price = seat.adult_seats * adult_price
        end
        if not seat.child_seats.blank?
            price = price + (seat.child_seats * child_price)
        end
        if not seat.senior_seats.blank?
            price = price + (seat.senior_seats * senior_price)
        end
        if not seat.student_seats.blank?
            price = price + (
            seat.student_seats * student_price)
        end
    end
    price
end
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError in Bookings#index 
Showing C:/Sites/Thor/Under Construction/ThorCinema/new/Lab/Newu/ThorCinema/app/views/bookings/index.html.erb where line #113 raised: 
Array can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

The line it is referring to in bookings/index.html.erb is:

```
<% if not booking.total_price.blank? %><%= booking.total_price %><% end %>
```

Can anyone help?

I can determine that the error is something to do with the prices that are being picked because if I change the method to:

```
def total_price
    adult_price = Price.where("name = ?", "Adult").pluck(:price)
end
```

This displays on the view:

```
    [#<BigDecimal:b20cbd8,'0.95E1',18(36)>]
```

This is the schema of the bookings and prices table:

```
create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "showing_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  t.integer  "adult_seats"
  t.integer  "child_seats"
  t.integer  "senior_seats"
  t.integer  "student_seats"
  t.integer  "disabled_seats"
  t.integer  "immortal_seats"
end

create_table "prices", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "name"
  t.decimal  "price"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Comment: Let your own code tell you what it is doing.   seats.each do |seat|, then logger.debug price.inspect.  And unless your bookings are ordered, the price charge for adults seats is potentially wrong. What happens if you don't hit the adult seat first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API Doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) `pluck` returns an array.

Try to extract the last element of the pluck and display it in the view.

So, essentially, what you might be looking at would be 
`Price.where("name = ?", "Adult").pluck(:price).last`
or `Price.where("name = ?", "Adult").pluck(:price).first`

Comment: Nice catch @Vineeth. Since `pluck(:price) ` returns an array, `total_price` method returns an array, and causes the `Array can't be coerced into Fixnum` error.